FBX import from Mixamo has arms up
I downloaded a model and animation from Mixamo and when I try to import it to Blender 3.4 it gets imported with its arms up. When I import it with Blender 4.2 it looks good. I'm using the same import settings. I need to use Blender 3.4 to use the Mixamo plugin. Any idea how to fix the posture? Thanks!
3.4 looks like this:

4.2 looks like this:

import setting for both are:

Edit: downloaded Blender version 3.6 and it works!

The Mixamo plugin has been updated so that you can use it with Blender 4.2 if you wish. You can download it here: https://gitlab.com/x190/mixamo_blender4.

@JohnEason wonderful! Thanks!
